# Blur page with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve a blur-page effect as an action from a pop up dialog box. How can I do this in HTML and CSS?

Comment: You can't blur the background, but as the answers below have already mentioned, you can darken or obscure the background.

Answer (score 3):

Thickbox

- http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

Fontbox

- http://www.mehdiplugins.com/misc/frontbox.htm

FancyBox

- http://fancybox.net/

FancyZoom

- http://www.cabel.name/draft1/2008/02/fancyzoom-10.html

SlimBox

- http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox

Shadowbox

- http://www.shadowbox-js.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about blurring, but [Lightbox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/) might do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

Lightbox, or the more technical term a "Modal Popup"

if you're using ASP.NET you can use the ModalPopupExtender withinthe AjaxToolKit

Answer (score 0):

There's also BlockUI plugin for the jQuery framework.

Check out the demos on the following site:

http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos

To use the plugin, you'll need to include the jQuery framework code. This is dead simple. You can download the jQuery code for free, and include it on your site from

http://www.jquery.com

With this and a lot of solutions given, you may need a  that is hidden initally. The div becomes the content of the popup.